# iOS Core Data - Can you include the coredata framework through code?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios4

I'm trying to build out a static library for a module i've developed for others to use.  the library requires the use of core data.  Is there any way I can load the coredata framework through code so that the user doesn't have to manually add it to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm pretty sure it's not possible. I've added quite a few third party libraries and you're often instructed to include frameworks manually. Anyone that uses your module will probably be used to adding frameworks manually, so I don't think it will be much of a problem.

Comment: has it right. To include it in text you'd effectively have to include it in your library. You future users won't be inconvenienced by a need to add the framework because it's an expected requirement.

Comment: thanks, that's what i thought but just wanted to double check.